# Mozilla Firefox Webextensions Upload my first Extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have done everything good in my webextentions from chrome to mozilla firefox nightly and its playing 100% good in nightly.
But when i try to upload it to mozilla firefox addons site
it is asking me for one installation file rdf.

But i dont have any.
Only the .xpi file.
Does anyone know what to do for this???

Comment: @wOxxOm but here is also one verified way to ask questions about webextensions and generally mozilla stuff :P

Comment: It seems crazy to me to have announced webextensions without any support for them...

Comment: @erikvold there is a support site... look at the answer below ;)

Comment: if you can't upload a webextension to amo then there is no support imo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Mozilla wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebExtensions) says ([authored on 15 Aug 2015](https://wiki.mozilla.org/index.php?title=WebExtensions&diff=1090330&oldid=1090328)):

> We do not yet support publishing WebExtensions to addons.mozilla.org. We hope to have that in place in a few weeks.

For an updated info see [the addon development support site](https://discourse.mozilla-community.org/c/add-ons/development).